# Is there a way to write code to test Stream in Flutter in the form of Given When Then?

Tags: flutter, testing, stream

I want to write test that is form of Given When Then.

For Streams, this would be written in the form of Given Then When.
This is because we need to be subscribed before we can get the value of that Stream.

The current code looks like this:

```
// Given

// When
scheduleMicrotask((){
  // do
})

// Then
expectLater Stream.
```

However, I think this code currently looks bad in terms of both readability and difficulty.
Is there an easy way to write tests that follow the given when then format?

When searching for tests in Junit or other languages, I've found that it's often better to not necessarily follow the Given When Then format.